Given a function defined on half its period, I want to extend it numerically to the whole period with the highest possible regularity
Suppose that I have a function like $f(x) = \exp(x)$ defined on $[0, \pi]$. I would like to extend it numerically to $[0, 2\pi]$, in such a way that the resulting function is periodic of period $2\pi$. An obvious solution is $f(\pi + x) = f(\pi - x)$, for $x$ in $[0, \pi]$, but in this case, $f(x)$ is only continuous in $x = \pi$. How can I define $f(x)$ on $[\pi, 2 \pi]$, so the resulting function is periodic and as regular as possible? Bear in mind that, in general, an expression of $f(x)$ will not be known, but just a collection of points, so the derivatives on $x = 0$ and $x = \pi$ can be computed only approximately.
Thank you in advance.

Consider a smooth bump function, for example,
$$b(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{1-2\left|x\right|}{x^{2}-\left|x\right|}}}$$
and an extension of the function $f$ to $(-\epsilon, \pi+\epsilon)$. If your $\epsilon$ is very small, you need to squish your bump function i.e. consider $b(\alpha x+\beta)$ for some $\alpha$ large, so that the expression below is well-defined. Then
$$f(x)b\left(1-\frac x{\pi}\right)+f(x-2\pi)b\left(\frac x{\pi}-2\right)$$
is a smooth extension of $f$ to the torus, since near $\pi$ all the derivatives of the second term vanish, and vice versa near $2\pi$.
The Whitney extension theorem says that the extension of $f$ to $(-\epsilon, \pi+\epsilon)$ always exists, but there probably is a less high powered way of proving that.

Thank you for your answer, but I rather work with a collection of points $f_0, \ldots, f_{N-1}$ coming from a function $f(x)$ defined on $[0,\pi)$, and want to find $f_N,\ldots, f_{2N-1}$ points corresponding to its extension to $[pi,2\pi)$, in such a way that the $2N$ points $f_0\ldots,f_{2N-1}$ correspond to a periodic function $f(x)$ of period $2\pi$ which is as regular as possible. The example with $f(x)=\exp(x)$ is one I am interested in, but in principle, you only have the points $f_0, \ldots, f_{N-1}$ and might not even know the explicit expression of the function $f(x)$ they come from.

@User I think you can choose a smooth interpolating function and then apply what I said in the answer.
